# Threaded loading (waiting) screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, screen, loading

I'm looking for a generic method to implement a wait screen during long operations. I have used threading a few times before, but I have the feeling that I implemented it either very poorly, or with way too much hassle (and copy/pasting - the horror!).

I want to keep this as generic and simple as possible, so I won't have to implement loads of `BackgroundWorker`s handling all kinds of crap, making things hard to maintain.

Here's what I would like to do -- please note this might differ from what's actually possible/best practise/whatever -- using VB.NET, Framework 2.0 (so no anonymous methods):

```
  Private Sub HandleBtnClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
      LoadingScreen.Show()

      'Do stuff here, this takes a while!'
      Dim Result as Object = DoSomethingTakingALongTime(SomeControl.SelectedObject)

      LoadingScreen.Hide()

      ProcessResults(Result)
  End Sub
```

The application is now completely single-threaded, so everything runs on the GUI thread. I need to be able to access objects in `DoSomethingTakingALongTime()` without getting cross-thread exceptions. The GUI thread waits for some method (which takes a long time) to complete, while the `LoadingScreen` Form should stay responsive (it's animated/has a progressbar/etc.).

Is this a doable/good approach or am I seeing this way too simplistic? What is the best practise concerning this matter? And most importantly: how could I implement such a system? As I already mentioned, I have very little experience with threading, so be gentle please :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your getting a cross thread exception when your trying to pass your Worker thread data to your ui thread. what you need to do is check InvokeRequired and begininvoke before setting the controls on your ui so you don't get the error like so:

```
Private Sub work_CrossThreadEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles work.CrossThreadEvent

       If Me.InvokeRequired Then
           Me.BeginInvoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf work_CrossThreadEvent), New Object() {sender, e})
           Return
       End If

      Me.Text = "Cross Thread"

End Sub
```

just change the `New EventHandler` part to the event handler your using.

Also i think using a background worker isn't a bad method for your worker classes, 
just create a class for your work and use the background worker to do the threading stuff a bit like this:

```
Public MustInherit Class Worker

    Protected WithEvents worker As BackgroundWorker

    Public Sub New()

        worker = New BackgroundWorker()
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    End Sub

    Public Sub Start()

        If (Not worker.IsBusy AndAlso Not worker.CancellationPending) Then
            worker.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Cancel()
        If (worker.IsBusy AndAlso Not worker.CancellationPending) Then
            worker.CancelAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub Work()

    Private Sub OnDoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker.DoWork
        Work()
    End Sub

    Public Event WorkCompelted As RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler
    Private Sub OnRunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles worker.RunWorkerCompleted
        OnRunWorkerCompleted(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overridable Sub OnRunWorkerCompleted(ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent WorkCompelted(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Public Event ProgressChanged As ProgressChangedEventHandler
    Private Sub OnProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles worker.ProgressChanged
        OnProgressChanged(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overridable Sub OnProgressChanged(ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ProgressChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ActualWork
    Inherits Worker

    Public Event CrossThreadEvent As EventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub Work()

        'do work here'
        WorkABit()
        worker.ReportProgress(25)

        WorkABit()
        worker.ReportProgress(50)

        WorkABit()
        worker.ReportProgress(75)

        WorkABit()
        worker.ReportProgress(100)

    End Sub

    Private Sub WorkABit()

        If worker.CancellationPending Then Return
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        RaiseEvent CrossThreadEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty)

    End Sub

End Class
```

*disclaimer.. bit rusty with vb but you should get the idea.*

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this and get back to you :-)

Comment: Very, very helpful. A great explanation in plain English. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your thread, use Application.Run(yourform) to get what you want.

Note that you need to signal the form to close itself somehow.

Comment: Which thread? The application is built single-threaded (= GUI thread), which already uses Application.Run to show the main form.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't find this unhelpful - but I'd question WHY you'd want a threaded wait screen?  The reason for using threading in the first place is so that the UI remains responsive, and long operations are done in the background.

Otherwise, you might as well just have a ProgressBar on your FormLoading control, and have DoSomethingTakingALongTime to update it periodically.  This wouldn't need threads at all.

Comment: .NET is very picky about when and how it updates the GUI. Sometimes it runs fine until you click somewhere, and it completely stops updating. I know long operations should be executed in a thread instead of the GUI, but I didn't mention it because I want to know if this solution is feasbible.

Comment: <continued> I don't really care about the main form, only the loading screen should be responsive. Nor do I care in which thread logic is executed, but I can't seem to get it right, I always run into cross-thread exceptions...